# How do I securely store/distribute application data for a Windows application

Tags: c++, security, windows-installer, msix, microsoft-store

I am developing a Windows Desktop Application using *C++ MFC*, and I want to securely store *API keys*, during the **installation process**. Ideally I do not want third party applications to be able to access the information.

The desktop native application, will be using the *API keys* for *OAUTH* flows. The *API keys* are sensitive, and could potentially be used to impersonate the application, and should be protected.

I have considered encrypting the *API keys*, and store them encrypted on *DISK* using [DPAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata), but the installer might carry the information in the clear, and perhaps the installer might not offer *DPAPI*. Also when using *DPAPI*, it's not 100% secure, as other third party installed applications can read the keys.

Do Windows application installers offer *DPAPI* or another mechanism for this purpose?

**What is the recommended approach for securing *API keys* or sensitive information on Windows 10 and 11, during installation**. (*Perhaps not using *API keys* for Desktop applications is the safest option*)

> I am hoping for a simple solution similar to what *Android*, *IOS* or *MacOS* has, where only the signed application with its unique application identifier, can access its own securely stored data.

Comment: `Please` don't use `inline code` for text that `aren't code`, which is everything here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to capture/ask the user for the API key in the installer GUI?

If so, the only option is to store it inside a [hidden property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/msihiddenproperties), assuming you plan to build an MSI-based installer. It's not bulletproof but it provides a little bit of security.

After that, you can write your own [custom action](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-c-sharp-ca.html) to process the value of the property and pass it to your application or save it somehow.

A safer method would be to ask the user to [provide you with a file](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-browse-for-file.html) that contains the API key, so your installer never has access to the direct value of the key. Then you can write a custom action that reads the value from the file directly, bypassing the use of any MSI properties which in some cases can be exposed.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*